# Cannot instantiate initialcontext on standalone client

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, jms, mom

I have a standalone client that I do not want to deploy on my Glassfish server. With the client I want to post message via the Point to Point communication pattern. I found [this](http://www.packtpub.com/article/setting-glassfish-jms-and-working-message-queues) great tutorial, which uses annotations I cannot use because I have a standalone client. I found the following solution on stackoverflow:

```
Context jndiContext;
private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
private static Queue queue;

public TweetSender() throws NamingException{
    jndiContext = new InitialContext();
    connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) jndiContext.lookup("JMS/KwetterConnectionFactory");
    queue = (Queue) jndiContext.lookup("JMS/KwetterQueue");
}
```

I also found out that I had to import some libraries from the glassfish directory. So I did: [image: Project properties]

I get the following error:

```
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory]
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT

I found a temporary solution for the problem though I feel it's not the right one (I think I might get problems when I want to migrate the project. I removed the libraries which I retrieved from the Glassfish lib folder and added them using the "Absolute path".

Comment: This https://blogs.oracle.com/randystuph/entry/injecting_jndi_datasources_for_junit might help

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but no changes

Comment: Take a look at this question as well, maybe that's the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461310/how-can-i-bind-a-datasource-to-an-initialcontext-for-junit-testing

Answer (score 0):

A solution can be packing your standalone client application in a jar file, eg: myclient.jar.
And run it as an application client using `appclient` utility of GlassFish:

```
applcient -client myclient.jar
```

The `appclient` utility can be found here: [glassfish home dir]/glassfish/bin.