# how to used data source declared in tomee.xml in java class

Tags: java, datasource, apache-tomee

Hi i configure data source in tomee.xml file and web.xml file.this will work fine when i executing my project but i implmented test case where also i need to used when i used there then its will giving exception  javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial

This is my tomee.xml file

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <tomee>
       <Resource id="jdbc/mydb" type="DataSource">
             JdbcDriver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver    
             JdbcUrl jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
             UserName root
             Password root    
             JtaManaged false   
             InitialSize 50 
             MaxActive 100
             MaxIdle 3
       </Resource>
     </tomee>
```

This code is  working fine in Servlet but when i am writing  in java class  then its giving exception 
this is my java class for accessing

```
     Context initContext = new InitialContext();
     Context envContext  = (Context)initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
     DataSource ds = (DataSource)envContext.lookup("jdbc/mydb");
     con = ds.getConnection();
```

Answer (score 1):

In a Servlet environment you have a context already set up by the servlet engine. When you run outside of such an environment, you need to set up the context yourself.

See an example [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461310/how-can-i-bind-a-datasource-to-an-initialcontext-for-junit-testing)

Comment: i am using following for connecting but its giving error

Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty("url", "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/myschema");
properties.setProperty("maxActive", "10");
properties.setProperty("maxIdle", "8");
properties.setProperty("minIdle", "10");
properties.setProperty("maxWait", "10");
DataSource ds = BasicDataSourceFactory.createDataSource(properties);


BasicDataSourceFactory cannot be resolved